# Bash script buildscript error. Line 20: syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'

Tags: bash

In my bash script I'm getting an error:

`./buildscriptbuild.sh: line 20: syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'`

I have tested the below bash script in my local system.
Can anyone help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.

```bash
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/ec2-user/inoutserver
if git pull origin development; then
    if npm install; then
        if grunt build --force; then
            echo "build success"
        else
            if sudo cp -r dist/* /home/ec2-user/testfolder; then
                echo "deployment success!"
            fi
            else
            echo "deployment failed"
        fi
    else
        echo "build failed"
    fi
else
    echo "npm install failed"
fi
```

Comment: Look at the `if sudo cp -r dist/* /home/ec2-user/testfolder; then` if block... where's the `else` vs the `fi`?

Comment: How the script should be? Can someone correct the scripts?

Comment: Look at the pattern followed by every other if/else statement in your code; what's different about those to the line I pointed out above?

Comment: You have an `if` ... `fi` ... `else` sequence that really shouldn't be that way. The mistake would be a lot more obvious if you fixed the indentation, so that corresponding `if`, `else`, and `fi` keywords were at the same indentation level. Also, it'd be a lot clearer to rewrite this with the error conditions first, as an `if ! step1command; then echo "step 1 error"; elif ! step2command; then echo "step 2 error"; elif ! step3command;...` See [this](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/626403/how-and-why-to-avoid-excessive-nesting).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Why not post that comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

in the middle replace this :

```
        fi
        else
        echo "deployment failed"
```

by :

```
        else
           echo "deployment failed"
        fi
```